# HTML form - input validation with Alphanumeric with symbols ()._-‘ only

Tags: html

I want to validate below input with **Alphanumeric** and **()._-‘** symbol only.

`<input type="text" name="companyName" value="" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9()._-‘]+" title="Alphanumeric with symbols ()._-‘ only" required> </p>`

But, when I try the input, only **._‘** can be used, **()-** are not working.

Comment: Perhaps you need to escape them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape those characters. They have significance in RegEx and aren't treated as part of the expression. Try the following: `[A-Za-z0-9\(\)._\-‘]+`

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, with the exception of the '-' which probably needs to be first:
`[-A-Za-z0-9()._‘]`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. I don't know why, but the order for the pattern attribute matters.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="companyName" value="" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9()_.'-]+" title="Alphanumeric with symbols ()._-‘ only" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```